# Store multiple 2d arrays in a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am generating a `nxn` diagonal matrix, for example if `n=3` the generated matrix would be

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

then I am rotating the matrix `n-1` times,for example in the above case it is `2` times

```
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0

0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

I need to generate `n-1` variables automatically. Store the rotated matrix in the variables. Print the variable name and the matrix stored in it, for example the output should be like this

```
a1
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0

a2
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

Is there any way to generate variables automatically?. I am using c++ and I am learning it.

**UPDATE**

I stored those rotated matrices in variables using the logic u said. Now I have printed those matrices diagonally in `mxm` diagonal matrix where `m=n*n`, for example in my case `n=3` so `m=9`. The output looks like

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

But I need the output should be looked like

```
1 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0
0 1 0  0 0 0  0 0 0
0 0 1  0 0 0  0 0 0

0 0 0  0 0 1  0 0 0
0 0 0  1 0 0  0 0 0
0 0 0  0 1 0  0 0 0

0 0 0  0 0 0  0 1 0
0 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 1
0 0 0  0 0 0  1 0 0
```

I am stuck with the for loop.

Comment: *"I need to generate n-1 variables automatically"*. Sounds like you need a `std::vector`

Comment: how to use `std::vector`  @user.

Comment: "how to use std::vector" - Start by reading [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is usually implemented using a vector of vector in C++:

```
vector< vector<int> > myTwoDArray; // this will create an empty maxtrix
```

to initialize it with certain size, you can do:

```
vector< vector<int> > myTwoDArray(n, vector<int>(n)); 
//this will create a n*n 2D array in which every element is 0
```

Then to modify the elements, you can use the [] operator, e.g.

```
myTwoDArray[1][2] = 1; // row 1 col 2 is now 1(if we start counting from 0)
```

**Update**

To store numbers of 2D Matrix in n variables, it might be more organizable to store them in a vector. That is, we can simply apply the same logic to create a vector of 2D matrix(or we can view it as a 3D Array)

```
vector< vector< vector<int> > > store(n,  vector< vector<int> >(n, vector<int>(n)));
```

For example, if `n=3`, then `store[0]`, `store[1]`, `store[2]` will each hold a 3*3 matrix.
To change the element of the matrix of each "variable", you can simply:

```
store[0][1][2] = 2; //change row 1, col 2 of the matrix in variable 0 to 2
```

Another really nice and simpler way to initialize the matrix would be to use the C++11 initialization list(make sure your compiler support C++11):

```
store[0] = { {0,0,1}, {1,0,0}, {0,1,0} }; //store[0] will be a1 in your example.
```

**Update2**
Print out the matrices like that can be tricky. Just try to break it into different parts, and this is one possible way:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { //There are n main blocks(i.e. n big 3*9 horizontal rows
       for(int j=0; j<n; j++){ //In each block, we have n individual rows
           for(int k=0; k<n; k++) { //In each individual row, we have a row from a matrix
               for(int m =0; m<n; m++) { //for the row in the matrix, there are n elements
                   cout << store[i*n+k][j][m]<<" ";
               }
               cout << " ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
       if(i!=n-1)
           cout<< endl; //avoid a new line at the very end.
   }
```

Comment: But how to create `n` number of vectors automatically. In my case I need to assign `n-1` number of rotated matrices to `n-1` number of vectors and print them.

Comment: @Praveen kumar sorry, I dont’t quite understand your question. Do you mean you wat to store the n-1 rotated matrices a vector? if so, apply the same logic and create a vector<vector<vector<int>>>>.

Comment: sorry for my inconvinient explanation...my question is "can we generate 'n' number of variables?" in which each variable should hold a 2d matrix. If yes, please tell me the logic.

Comment: @Praveenkumar I have updated my answer, let me know if this is what you are asking.

Comment: Exactly gchen. thank you for the clear explanation and the logic works fine. :)

Comment: May I ask you another doubt gchen?

Comment: @Praveenkumar sure! more than happy to help.

Comment: thank you gchen. I have updated my question. please check.

Comment: @Praveenkumar I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much @gchen :D Its working perfectly.